# Postgresql get updated by sql script, get notification in backend

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I'm using django-rest-framework as backend and postgresql as the database. The database might be changed by raw SQL script and I want to get notified in the backend when those changes happen so that I can notify different users about the change.

I've checked about posts like https://gist.github.com/pkese/2790749 for receiving notification in python and some SQL scripts for

```
CREATE TRIGGER rec_notify_trig AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON rec
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE rec_notify_func()
```

My question is that I don't know how to hook them together in the django-rest-framework, like where should I put the SQL script, where to put the python settup so that I can connect them together. Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create an endpoint on the djangorestframework side to accept a notification.

Then, in your `rec_notify_func()` you can call out and hit your endpoint where you can perform any enduser notification necessary.

```
CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u; 
CREATE FUNCTION rec_notify_func(notification_endpoint_uri text) RETURNS text AS $$
  from urllib.request import urlopen
  data = urlopen(notification_endpoint_uri)
  return data.read()
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```

> NOTE: 
>   You need to have plpython installed on the system in order to enable the extension.
>
> On ubuntu something like this:
>   `sudo apt-get install postgresql-plpython3-9.6`